# capture auto populated textbox values and echo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a code in jquery, which is generating textbox's after selecting check-boxes. I want to capture the entered data in dynamically generated data and echo the same in a text area in csv format.

Whenever, user selects 1 checkbox two textbox's are generated. However, I want the entered data to be in csv echoed in a new texbox/area.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        function updateTextArea() {

            var allVals = [];

            $('#mydiv :checked').each(function () {

                allVals.push($(this).val());

            });

            $('#txtValue').val(allVals)

        }

        $(function () {

            $('#mydiv input').click(updateTextArea);

            updateTextArea();

        });

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function dynInput(cbox) {
      if (cbox.checked) {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        var input1 = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var div1 = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = cbox.name;
        div.innerHTML = "Enter Max Size of " + cbox.name;
        div1.innerHTML = "Enter Min Size of " + cbox.name;
        div.appendChild(input);
        div.appendChild(input1);
        document.getElementById("insertinputs").appendChild(div); 
        document.getElementById("insertinputs").appendChild(div1);
      } else {
        document.getElementById(cbox.name).remove();
      }
    }
    </script>
```

HTML CODE:

```
  <div id="mydiv">
        <input type="checkbox" name="1 RK Apartment" id="1 RK Apartment" value="1 RK" onClick="dynInput(this);"/> 1 RK Apartment<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="1 BHK Apartment" id="1 BHK Apartment" value="1 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 1 BHK Apartment<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="1.5 BHK Apartment" id="1.5 BHK Apartment" value="1.5 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 1.5 BHK Apartment<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="2 BHK Apartment" id="2 BHK Apartment" value="2 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 2 BHK Apartment<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="2.5 BHK Apartment" id="2.5 BHK Apartment" value="2.5 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 2.5 BHK Apartment<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="3 BHK Apartment" id="3 BHK Apartment" value="3 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 3 BHK Apartment<br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="3.5 BHK Apartment" id="3.5 BHK Apartment" value="3.5 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 3.5 BHK Apartment <br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="4 BHK Apartment" id="4 BHK Apartment" value="4 BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 4 BHK Apartment <br />

        <input type="checkbox" name="4+ BHK Apartment" id="4+ BHK Apartment" value="4+ BHK" onClick="dynInput(this);" /> 4+ BHK Apartment <br />

        <textarea id="txtValue" name="config"></textarea>
     </div>   
     </tr>
```

Comment: Please don't tag spam. This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Sorry, got confused. Basically The application is in php.